# sqoop import using exclude tables

Tags: sqoop

I have 100 tables in a MySQL database, using sqoop import-all-tables I want to import only 50 tables to hdfs, using exclude command we have to specify 50 tables or there is any other option?

Answer (score 0):

Yes You are right You can use Sqoop `"import-all-tables"` along with  another parameter, `--exclude-tables`,with which you can exclude some of the table that you don't want to import in the database. 
Another option you can try is shell script as below:

1)Prepare a inputfile which has list of DBNAME.TABLENAME

2)The shell script will have this file as input, iterate line by line and execute sqoop statement for each line

```
while read line;
do

    DBNAME=`echo $line | cut -d'.' -f1` 
    tableName=`echo $line | cut -d'.' -f2`


    sqoop import -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=$QUEUE_NAME --connect '$JDBC_URL;databaseName=$DBNAME;username=$USERNAME;password=$PASSWORD' --table $tableName  --target-dir $DATA_COLLECTOR/$tableName  --fields-terminated-by '\001'  -m 1 

done<inputFile
```